# Constantly getting 'Too many connections' in Django 1.4.20

Tags: mysql, django

I currently have an app running with MySQL in webfaction. The database is a private one, and Every 12 hours or so, I get a 'Too many connections' error intermittently.

So I logged as root into mysql to check the number of active connections

```
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects               | 4     |
| Com_enable_governor_reconn     | 0     |
| Com_enable_governor_reconn_lve | 0     |
| Connections                    | 12    |
| Max_used_connections           | 1     |
| Ssl_client_connects            | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates       | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects          | 0     |
| Threads_connected              | 1     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
```

Note that Max_used_connections = 1 (???!!!) Weird. Ok, so maybe there is a problem with processes...

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 12 | root | localhost:38884 | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or max connections is set to an unexplainably low number...

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 151   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I give up. This seems like A) I ran into one of those really obscure errors or B) I need a vacation.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

EDIT: found the problem

The problem was being caused by a `for object in Model.object.iterator()` loop in a background task running with cron. As it turns out, there was an issue with yielding and connections being properly closed. Changed that to `.all()` and it worked properly.

Lessons learned: 1) avoid using `.iterator()` with background tasks; 2) avoid using app database for background tasks, when possible.

Comment: The answer is always **(B)**

Comment: plus one for making me feel worse.

Comment: Are you doing anything with `Thread`s?

Comment: Yes, cronjobs actually. And I think it might be that they are piling up.

Comment: do you close the mysql connection somewhere ,using `close()` or `execute()` or similar  ?

Comment: I'm using Django's ORM, so my guess is yes. I'll check, though.

Comment: Yes. all connections are closing.

Comment: Finally found the problem. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: hey misterte, could you explain what was the actual problem with the iterators and yielding? I'm running into similar problems and wondering where to look.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by increasing the maximum number of connections allowed by MySQL in my django app settings.py file. More information in
[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

```
DATABASES = { 
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
           "init_command": "SET GLOBAL max_connections = 100000", #<-- The fix
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is just a bandage and not a solution

Comment: a helpful bandage

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are connection to the right database ?

this part seems little bit odd.

```
| Connections                    | 12    |
```

That means that you got only 12 connections to db since its start.
If your application is using that db then this number should be bigger.

If mysql uptime is not few sec than this number is wrong for db, that some application is using. If mysql uptime is only few sec than that output is useless and you need to provide output after db is used for a while.

Try checking your db connection settings in your application.